# How to autocalculate quiz score in a simple HTML and vanilla JavaScript quiz?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a 3 questions quiz I've created for exercise. The quiz itself works, but I want to improve it a bit (see below). The quiz is made up of the following code:

```js
let result = 0;

let right = ()=>{
 result += 33.3;
};

let wrong = ()=>{
 result -= 33.3;
};

let finish = ()=>{
 totalScore = result;

 if (totalScore < 0) {
  totalScore = 0;
 }

 alert(Math.ceil(totalScore));
}
```

```html
<form id="quiz">
 <div>
  <label>Q1 - X?</label>
  <input type="radio" name="g1" onclick="right()">Yes</input>
  <input type="radio" name="g1" onclick="wrong()">No</input>
 </div>
 <div>
  <label>Q2 - Y?</label>
  <input type="radio" name="g2" onclick="wrong()">Yes</input>
  <input type="radio" name="g2" onclick="right()">No</input>
 </div>
 <div>
  <label>Q2 - Y?</label>
  <input type="radio" name="g3" onclick="right()">Yes</input>
  <input type="radio" name="g3" onclick="wrong()">No</input>
 </div>
 <br>
 <input type="button" value="finish" onclick="finish()"></input>
</form>
```

I try time and again to figure out how make the points calculation automatic, instead me changing each time like `result += 50` (for 2 questions) or `result +=33.3` (for 3 questions) as it would be more efficient, but I have failed so far.

I don't know what to try for that **or what to search for that**. I can't see how this should be written basically.

Maybe an answer should be based upon dividing 100 by the number of questions, based on number of `label` tags in the form (`let labelCount = document.querySelectorAll('#quiz label').length;`), and than compare with right and wrong answers.

But I have no idea how to integrate and process that data with the `right()` and `wrong()` functions.

What approach will you take to auto calculate the `totalScore`?

### Update

Please see George's answer, and then, my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right in using `let labelCount = document.querySelectorAll('#quiz label').length;` to get the amount of labels and then doing `100/labelCount`. All you need to do then is store that value and replace `33.3` with that value, like below

**Three Questions Example**

```js
let result = 0;
let labelCount = document.querySelectorAll('#quiz label').length;
let questionValue = 100 / labelCount;


let right = () => {
  result += questionValue;
};

let wrong = () => {
  result -= questionValue;
};

let finish = () => {
  totalScore = result;

  if (totalScore < 0) {
    totalScore = 0;
  }

  alert(Math.ceil(totalScore));
}
```

```html
<form id="quiz">
  <div>
    <label>Q1 - X?</label>
    <input type="radio" name="g1" onclick="right()" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="g1" onclick="wrong()" />No
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Q2 - Y?</label>
    <input type="radio" name="g2" onclick="wrong()">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="g2" onclick="right()">No
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Q2 - Y?</label>
    <input type="radio" name="g3" onclick="right()">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="g3" onclick="wrong()">No
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="finish" onclick="finish()">
</form>
```

**Four Questions Example**

```js
let result = 0;
let labelCount = document.querySelectorAll('#quiz label').length;
let questionValue = 100 / labelCount;


let right = () => {
  result += questionValue;
};

let wrong = () => {
  result -= questionValue;
};

let finish = () => {
  totalScore = result;

  if (totalScore < 0) {
    totalScore = 0;
  }

  alert(Math.ceil(totalScore));
}
```

```html
<form id="quiz">
  <div>
    <label>Q1 - X?</label>
    <input type="radio" name="g1" onclick="right()" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="g1" onclick="wrong()" />No
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Q2 - Y?</label>
    <input type="radio" name="g2" onclick="wrong()">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="g2" onclick="right()">No
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Q3 - Y?</label>
    <input type="radio" name="g3" onclick="right()">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="g3" onclick="wrong()">No
  </div>
    <div>
    <label>Q4 - Y?</label>
    <input type="radio" name="g4" onclick="right()">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="g4" onclick="wrong()">No
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="finish" onclick="finish()">
</form>
```

Comment: ohh sorry was inverted yes  or not to rest or sum, sorry sorry, please let me put one positive only for my crazy error ;)

Comment: How about clicking same radio button?? It will increase my score.

Comment: Thanks @George. Just one thing: In the 4 questions quiz in the snippet, I did: Yes, No, Yes Yes, and got 75 instead 100. Why is it? In group two No has right() so I should have got 100. I've published an answer with my version of the quiz.

Answer (score 0):

`Let` with `right` and `wrong` is creating local scope of `result` and not using the result's value global to it at the time of execution of `right` and `wrong` function.

You need to use `var right` and `var wrong`

**Demo**

```js
let result = 0;

var right = ()=>{ //see the change here. `let` is replaced with `var`
 result += 33.3;
};

var wrong = ()=>{ //see the change here. `let` is replaced with `var`
 result -= 33.3;
};

let finish = ()=>{
 totalScore = result;
 if (totalScore < 0) {
  totalScore = 0;
 }
 console.log(Math.ceil(totalScore));
}
```

```html
<form id="quiz">
 <div>
  <label>Q1 - X?</label>
  <input type="radio" name="g1" onclick="right()">Yes</input>
  <input type="radio" name="g1" onclick="wrong()">No</input>
 </div>
 <div>
  <label>Q2 - Y?</label>
  <input type="radio" name="g2" onclick="wrong()">Yes</input>
  <input type="radio" name="g2" onclick="right()">No</input>
 </div>
 <div>
  <label>Q2 - Y?</label>
  <input type="radio" name="g3" onclick="right()">Yes</input>
  <input type="radio" name="g3" onclick="wrong()">No</input>
 </div>
 <br>
 <input type="button" value="finish" onclick="finish()"></input>
</form>
```

> I try time and again to figure out how make the points calculation
>   automatic, instead me changing each time like result += 50 (for 2
>   questions) or result +=33.3 (for 3 questions) as it would be more
>   efficient, but I have failed so far.

You can follow this approach

- Assign the `data-isCorrect` value to the radio button itself.
- Remove the `onclick` attribute and add a *click event* by iterating all the radio buttons.

**Demo with 4 questions**

```js
let result = 0;
var radios = document.querySelectorAll( "input[type='radio']" );

[].slice.call( radios ).forEach( function( element ){   
   element.addEventListener( "click", function(){
       var isCorrect = this.getAttribute( "data-isCorrect" ) == "true";
       result += isCorrect ? 33.3 : -33.3;
   });
});

let finish = ()=>{
 totalScore = result;
 if (totalScore < 0) {
  totalScore = 0;
 }
 console.log(Math.ceil(totalScore));
}
```

```html
<form id="quiz">
 <div>
  <label>Q1 - X?</label>
  <input type="radio" name="g1" data-isCorrect="true">Yes</input>
  <input type="radio" name="g1" data-isCorrect="false">No</input>
 </div>
 <div>
  <label>Q2 - Y?</label>
  <input type="radio" name="g2" data-isCorrect="false">Yes</input>
  <input type="radio" name="g2" data-isCorrect="true">No</input>
 </div>
 <div>
  <label>Q3 - Y?</label>
  <input type="radio" name="g3" data-isCorrect="true">Yes</input>
  <input type="radio" name="g3" data-isCorrect="false">No</input>
 </div>
 <div>
  <label>Q4 - Y?</label>
  <input type="radio" name="g3" data-isCorrect="true">Yes</input>
  <input type="radio" name="g3" data-isCorrect="false">No</input>
 </div>
 <br>
 <input type="button" value="finish" onclick="finish()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on George's answer and my additions, here is a fully working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="quiz">
            <div>
                <label>Q1 - X?</label>
                <input type="radio" name="g1" onclick="right()" />Yes
                <input type="radio" name="g1" onclick="wrong()" />No
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Q2 - Y?</label>
                <input type="radio" name="g2" onclick="wrong()">Yes
                <input type="radio" name="g2" onclick="right()">No
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Q3 - Z?</label>
                <input type="radio" name="g3" onclick="right()">Yes
                <input type="radio" name="g3" onclick="wrong()">No
            </div>

            <!-- -->

            <div>
                <input type="button" value="finish" onclick="finish()">
            </div>
        </form>

        <script>
            let result = 0;
            let labelCount = document.querySelectorAll('#quiz label').length;
            let questionValue = 100 / labelCount;

            let right = ()=>{
                result += questionValue;
            };

            let wrong = ()=>{
                result -= questionValue;
            };

            let finish = ()=>{
                let labelCount = document.querySelectorAll('#quiz label').length;
                let checkedButtonsCount = document.querySelectorAll('#quiz :checked').length;
                if (labelCount !== checkedButtonsCount) {
                    alert("At least one group is blank.");
                }
                if (result < 0) {
                    result = 0;
                }
                if (result > 100) {
                    result = 100;
                }
                return alert(Math.ceil(result));
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this example there isn't the problem I had with George's version (see comments). I've also added a check to see if all radio buttons are clicked, and a return for the alert.